# On OAuth (1.0a and 2.0) and Http Basic Auth

Tags: security, http, authentication, ssl, oauth

I am trying to figure out what would the best choice be in terms of security for a web application that might (in the future) be used with as well with a dedicated Android app.

Yet, the possibile choices I've been through are OAuth (2-legged) and Basic Http Authentication via TLS.

Please keep in mind that when I refer to OAuth, I am considering both OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0, of course as different alternatives.

Here are my doubts:

1) First, would it make any sense nowadays to set up a security system based on OAuth 1.0a? Should it be considered "too old" and hence a completely wrong pick?

2) I can't figure out a real world scenario where 2-legged OAuth is cleary a better option then Http(S) Auth. What extra bonuses do I get from it?

3) Given that I'm not a veteran security expert, would OAuth be a reasonable choice?

4) Are there support frameworks or other third-party auxiliary tools that one may use in order to obtain a secure-reliable-thrustworty implementation of OAuth in less time and/or with less effort than just trying to figure it out completely by him/herself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It absolutely makes sense. My personal opinion is, that OAuth 1.0a should still be the preferred solution, unless you are absolutely sure that you need OAuth 2. OAuth1 is a strictly defined secure protocol, OAuth2 is a "framework" which is used to create protocols, some of which are less secure.
2. The main difference is, that when using OAuth you never send password over the wire. Also, your android application doesn't need to know user's password. And if you don't know the password you can't be blamed for leaking it.
3. OAuth 1.0a is a perfectly reasonable choice. Just make sure to use long (I mean 1K+ long) secrets. Secret is not transmitted with requests, so it won't eat the bandwidth but it is used for generating digital signatures.
4. There are. But as you're interested in android and I'm not an android specialist I'll leave this to others. You will have better chances for a good answer if you ask this question separately

Comment: Thanks for your help. About point 2, since I'm working on my *own* application (no third parties at all), would it really matter if passwords are being sent in place of tokens? Because strictly speaking about a "private" scenario, I'm still unconvinced that OAuth would be of any use more than Basic Auth would. Would by any mean a malicious user A steal user B's token, he could still use my web app (or mobile app) pretending to be B, being able to do exactly (and no more) what he could do in a basic auth protected environment, since user/pass would only work for this particoular purpose. Right?

Comment: @Seether the difference is, that user might have used the same password somewhere else. so, if password is compromised in one place there is a chance that accounts of this user at other services are in danger.

Comment: @Seether also, it's easier to block oauth-token than user. you can provide a page on the web-site where user can see list of her oauth-sessions with last-used time, IP address and button to kill access token. this page of course should not be available via oauth :)

Comment: Ok, the bad habit of users always using the same passwords makes a point. But in fact, this is something that only depends on users, so we can't really blame the auth method here (at least not completely). The second point sounds way more interesting: so by using OAuth I would be able to provide a page - like gmail does - where I can allow users to review their sessions and revoke them. Now that's nice, so having stolen just a token (no password) would only allow me to keep the session alive until killed by the owner, and not being able to create a new one. Is it impossible to do with B. A.?

Comment: with BasicAuth login+password are the credentials of the user, so leak of those ultimately compromises account

Comment: Correct. Still, let's say user X logged in into someone else's PC and forgot the session open, without having the browser remember the password. Apart from sessions' natural expiring, is there any way to keep trace of - and kill - these "forgotten" open sessions? It would make sense, as long as along with it, the system suggests the users to change his/her login data. And if you think about it, even having OAuth, if I login from a remote position and have the browser remember my password, I'm done as well. I'd have to carry the auth token with me, which I think is not possibile.

Comment: Well those are some questions which you might try to ask separately. Short version: sessions give you ability to list and kill them, yes. BasicAuth is session-less so you don't have this option in this case. If you leave your password somewhere else — sure, that's a problem. But it is a problem initiated by user explicitly. You can make attack vector smaller, but you can't elimitate it completely. BasicAuth has a huge attack-vector. Sessions have smaller one. OAuth has even smaller one (as "secret" is not sent with requests)